# create mysql user following system

Tags: python, mysql, django

in my django web application users can post images. i need to create following system. that means user can follow post of other users like [tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com).

user 2 is following by user 1:

```
user_id | following
1       | 2
```

after user 2 create a post i'm store a post id to this table

tbl_user_stream

```
user_id|   post_id|   time  
1      |   25     |   1337460925   # this post for user 2
1      |   26     |   1337460726
```

if i need to display stream of user 1 execute query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts p 
INNER JOIN tbl_user_stream st on st.post_id=p.id 
ORDER BY st.time DESC
```

is this workflow works fine or we need a new solution? what about performance by this way?
somebody tell me best solution is using nosqls like mongodb.

Comment: normally, the only way to know if it _works fine_ is if you code it up and test it yourself. You will know if it _works fine_ or not and, afterwards, be able to tell **why** or **how** it doesn't work fine. Without more information I would probably suggest only one modification: add a LIMIT to the last query. If your system grows large enough, that query may bring in way too much data and the idea is to only show the most recent data so getting it all may be unnecessary.

Comment: It's hard to answer in short words. If you're only worrying about join, yes this would be slower *as users and posts grow*.

Comment: create test file and add milion user and hunder milion post. what can be happen? (milion is your limit, maybe 1000 is enough)